# GCM - Opening app from notification?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm working on an app which is using GCM for push notification.

My question is around how to open/start the app from when user clicks the notification.
I have two potential scenarios:

A) The app is open and is resident in either foreground or background, either way my GCM works fine, the GCM message arrives user taps notification and intent starts relevant activity (passed via the notification pending intent).

B) The app is closed and notification received, the user again taps the notification and the intent tries to start the relevant activity and this is where it gets messy.
The app has a back-end and so needs to auto-login/authenticate now if I try to start the same activity the credentials etc are out of date or dont exist therefore the app crashes. I need to launch the app from scratch in this case rather than simply start the particular activity via the pending-intent.

My question therefore is how do I tell the GCM listener to check if app running and if so simply start activity and if not (app is closed) launch app as normal?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok solved this, not sure if its the best way but appears to work without issue.

What I ended up doing was creating a static boolean variable in launcher activity.
This is set true when app starts and the GCM listener tests for this variables state on incoming GCM notif (will always be true for life of app instance), if true go directly to activity else (app closed or stale) launch app.

This seems to work fine from what I can see, still interested in a better method as this does seem hackish?